# Why the expression in switch condition cannot be a variable?

Tags: javascript

When I use `score` variable to replace the boolean value `true`, the code inside the curly braces cannot be executed. I am confused because the `score` variable is not `false`、`undefined`、`null`、`NaN`, the program inside the curly braces should run as expected.

I try to google this problem but cannot find a useful answer.

```
let response;
let score = 75;
let machineActive = true;

if(machineActive) {
    // Add your code here
  switch (**true**){
      case (score<0 || score> 100):
            //....
            break;
      case (score >=0 && score <= 19):
            //....
            break;
      default:
            //....
    }
} else {
  response = 'The machine is turned off. Turn it on to process your score.';
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `switch` with ranges. You should really be using if/else condition statements.

Comment: The code you've provided here indicates you have a very big misunderstanding about the proper syntax (and the utility, more broadly) of a `switch` statement. Have you reviewed [the MDN page for `switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)? How did you reach the conclusion that what you've got here is proper/correct use for this control structure? `switch(true)` is (likely almost) never the right solution, and instead indicates a proper `if`/`else` structure would be more advantageous as @Andy indicates.

Comment: You should take some time to read how the `switch` statement works. As @esqew mentioned, MDN can prove helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!
Sorry, I didn't describe the context in which this question arose.
It's a test and I was using `if... . else` statements to complete it, but now, it asks me to use `switch` statement.
Thanks @esqew @Andy @Stratis Dermanoutsos for the suggestion! I just checked the MDN page on switch and I think I got my answer:

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for
> the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as
> the result of the input expression (using the strict equality
> comparison) and transfers control to that clause, executing all
> statements following that clause.

Thanks again for your help!